# How to filter the Running jobs in a particular server in Autosys..?

Tags: unix, monitoring, autosys

I am new to Autosys. Is it possible to find all the running jobs on a particular server in Autosys. (Like what we are doing in TWS or other monitoring tools).

Answer (score 2):

The command to show running jobs on a specific server is this:
autorep -M servername -d

- note that the servername value has to match exactly what's in the JIL.
Also the output isn't detailed like you'd get from "autorep -d -j jobname" - but then it does what you asked!

If you want the job detail you might want to use the previous suggestion. Or you could use autorep -M as I suggested to get the running jobs and pipe that list through autorep -j to get detail just for those specific jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can find out the list of jobs running in autosys. Put the command in GUI as autorep -j %  | find " RU ". in Unix machine use grep in place of find

Answer (score 0):

autorep -M *agent_name* -d

autorep -M  -d shows jobs that are in running on the specified node.

autorep -M machine1 -d

Machine Name                                                                    Max Load  Current Load Factor  O/S        Status

---

machine1                                                          ---        ---          1.00    Sys Agent  Online

Current Jobs:
Job Name                                                        Machine                                          Status    Load  Priority

---

CMD1                                                            machine1                                          RUNNING    0      0
CMD2                                                            machine1                                          RUNNING    0      0

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with this answer. Could you reformat the code and add some explanation?

Answer (score -1):

autorep -I MachineName | Find "RU"

Comment: `Find: not found` (the question is tagged [tag:unix].) What does this add to [Pradhan Belur's 2015 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918403)?